# How can I do the job of three foreach loop by one foreach loop?

Tags: laravel

actually I am new to Laravel. I am doing a project for making a meal management system.
my code in my controller is:

```
$days=DB::table('days')
        ->get();

        foreach ($days as $day) {
        $breakfast[]= DB::table('breakfast_menus')
            ->leftJoin('breakfast_items', 'breakfast_menus.item_id', '=', 'breakfast_items.id')
            ->where('breakfast_menus.day_id',$day->id)
            ->select('breakfast_items.item')
            ->get();
        $lunch[]= DB::table('lunch_menus')
            ->leftJoin('lunch_items', 'lunch_menus.item_id', '=', 'lunch_items.id')
            ->where('lunch_menus.day_id',$day->id)
            ->select('lunch_items.item')
            ->get();

        $dinner[]= DB::table('dinner_menus')
            ->leftJoin('dinner_items', 'dinner_menus.item_id', '=', 'dinner_items.id')
            ->where('dinner_menus.day_id',$day->id)
            ->select('dinner_items.item')
            ->get();
}

return view('admin.show_menu',compact('days','breakfast','lunch','dinner'));
```

I want to show the data in a table. Where there will be

```
<td>day</td>
<td>Breakfast </td>
<td>Lunch</td>
<td>Dinner</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use Laravel relationships and do justice with the framework.

1. Create models for each table.
2. Define relationship like days has breakfast_manu. [See this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)
3. Then you will be able to do it like this:

```
$days = Days::with(['breakfast_menus','lunch_items','dinner_items'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can say the way you wrote are very very bad for performance, why don't you use another way round in sql?

```
$days = DB::table('days')
->leftJoin('breakfast_menus', function($q) {
    $q->leftJoin('breakfast_items', 'breakfast_menus.item_id', '=', 'breakfast_items.id')
        ->where('breakfast_menus.day_id', $day->id);
})
->leftJoin('lunch_menus', function($q) {
    $q->leftJoin('lunch_items', 'lunch_menus.item_id', '=', 'lunch_items.id')
        ->where('lunch_menus.day_id', $day->id);
})
->leftJoin('dinner_menus', function($q) {
    $q->leftJoin('dinner_items', 'dinner_menus.item_id', '=', 'dinner_items.id')
        ->where('dinner_menus.day_id', $day->id);
})
->select('days.id', 'breakfast_items.item as breakfast', 'lunch_items.item as lunch', 'dinner_items.item as dinner')
->get();
```

I didn't try out the SQL, but you can get the idea.

Then you can foreach $days to show your data

Comment: thanks a lot,
but one error is shown: Undefined variable: days

    ->where('breakfast_menus.day_id', $days->id);

should i use a foreach loop or something else?

Comment: if I use like this  " ->where('breakfast_menus.day_id','days.id');   "
then I got 
[{"id":1,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null},{"id":2,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null},{"id":3,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null},{"id":4,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null},{"id":5,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null},{"id":6,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null},{"id":7,"breakfast":null,"lunch":null,"dinner":null}]

Comment: pass variable into the sub-query, ->leftJoin('breakfast_menus', function($q) use ($day) { .. }